# How can I reference to model field in Django using String?

Tags: python, django

Consider my model (`MODEL`) has field has attribute `NAME`.

I want to reference to that model attribute using string.

eg. `var = Model.objects.get( pk=1 )`

`var.str('NAME') = value`

while trying with string it's giving me error :  can't assign to function call

P.S.: I know for finding a value of attribute from string I can use `getattr()` but since I want to assign value, this method isn't helpful.

Comment: How about `var['NAME'] = value`? I'm not at a computer right now so can't test

Comment: @Johan: no, that will not work. Django models are not subscriptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `setattr` function.

```
setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)
```

[More details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)